# ErrorException Trying to get property 'name' of non-object when try to search name from different database table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Hye, I want to make a search function of user id, name, and shift pattern id. All the searching functions work well for all but fail for name searching. FYI, the name is inside the user table & the user id and shift pattern id is inside the user shift pattern table.

****MODEL:-****

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserShiftPattern extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['name'];

  public function shiftpattern(){
    return $this->belongsTo(ShiftPattern::class, 'shift_pattern_id');
  }

  public function uspattern(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
  }

  public function name(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
  }
}
```

**CONTROLLER:-**

```
public function index(Request $req) {
    $usershiftpattern = [];
    if($req->filled('searching')){
        $usershiftpattern = $this->fetch($req);
    }
    return view('admin.usershiftpattern', ['usps' => $usershiftpattern]);
}
public function fetch(Request $req) {
    $fuserid = $req->inputuserid;
    $fname = explode(",", str_replace(' ','',$req->inputname));
    $fshiftpatternid = explode(",", str_replace(' ','',$req->inputshiftpatternid));
    $usershiftpatternlist = UserShiftPattern::query();
    if(isset($req->inputuserid)) {
            $usershiftpatternlist = $usershiftpatternlist->where('user_id','LIKE','%' .$fuserid. '%');
        }
        
        if(isset($req->inputname)){
            $usershiftpatternlist = $usershiftpatternlist->whereIn('name',$fname);
        }
        
        if(isset($req->inputshiftpatternid)){
            $usershiftpatternlist = $usershiftpatternlist->whereIn('shift_pattern_id',$fshiftpatternid);
        }
        $usershiftpatternlist = $usershiftpatternlist->get();

        return $usershiftpatternlist;
    }
```

**VIEW:-**

```
<div class="text-right">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" name="searching" value="filter" class="btn-up">SEARCH</button>
        </div>
            <br>
    </form>

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>User ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Shift Pattern ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($usps as $uspslist)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $uspslist->user_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $uspslist->uspattern->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $uspslist->shift_pattern_id }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

it because uspattern relationship is deleted in some $usps instance, to ignore this you can use null coalescing:

```
<td>{{ $uspslist->uspattern->name ?? "" }}</td>
```

or filter out the record that doesn't have uspattern relationship:

```
$usershiftpatternlist = $usershiftpatternlist->has('uspattern')->get();
```

you only need to use one of the above solutions

Comment: it did not work properly because all the design inside the table become messy and got error

Comment: I already try both solution, and get this tab error --> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: that's because your query is running too long use the first solution only (null coalescing) or increase max_execution_time in php.ini

Comment: if your database is too large, try to limit or pagination your data

Comment: omg, i try to search by name and other error appears--> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `user_shift_patterns` where `name` in (mas) and exists (select * from `users` where `user_shift_patterns`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`))

Comment: does user_shift_patterns  table has "name" column if name column in users table, then try $usershiftpatternlist->whereHas('uspattern', function($query){ $query->whereIn("name", ["mas"]) })->get();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232682/discussion-between-adda-and-chinh-nguyen).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
I get you now now include User model, like I have shown in comment, and
try to change your controllers like this, do not use lowercases to all variables name it becomes difficult to read instead of `$inputuserid` use `$inputUserId`

```
  public function fetch(Request $req) {
        $fuserid = $req->inputuserid;
        $fname = explode(",", str_replace(' ','',$req->inputname));
        $fshiftpatternid = explode(",", str_replace(' ','',$req->inputshiftpatternid));
        $usershiftpatternlist = new UserShiftPattern(); //change this line

        $user = new User(); //check user table
        if(isset($req->inputuserid)) {
                $usershiftpatternlist = $usershiftpatternlist->where('user_id','LIKE','%' .$fuserid. '%');
            }
            
            if(isset($req->inputname)){
                $usershiftpatternlist = $user->whereIn('name',$fname); //change to user variable
            }
            
            if(isset($req->inputshiftpatternid)){
                $usershiftpatternlist = $usershiftpatternlist->whereIn('shift_pattern_id',$fshiftpatternid);
            }
            $results = $usershiftpatternlist->get(); //change variable
    
            return $results; //change this too
        }
```

I hope it works

**USER DATABASE:-**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->integer('id')->primary('id')->unsigned();


        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->rememberToken();

        $table->string('staff_no');
        $table->integer('persno')->nullable();
        $table->string('new_ic')->unique();
        $table->string('company_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('orgunit')->nullable();
        $table->string('persarea',10)->nullable();
        $table->string('perssubarea',10)->nullable();
        $table->string('state_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('reptto')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

**USER SHIFT PATTERN DATABASE:-**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_shift_patterns', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('shift_pattern_id');
        $table->dateTime('start_date')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('end_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('sap_code', 20);
        $table->integer('created_by')->default(0);
        $table->string('source','5')->default('SAP');
        $table->dateTime('upd_sap')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: everything works fine but when i search for name, there's an error --> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `user_shift_patterns` where `name` = mas and exists (select * from `users` where `user_shift_patterns`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`))

Comment: can you show me the migration of that table

Comment: maybe you confused it with with fname, is that column name or fname I want to check, because that error means no column name isnt there

Comment: the name is inside the user table

Comment: while others is inside the user shift pattern table

Comment: I have updated my answer, If that you must do your check inside User model, hopefull it works now

Comment: got error,  Call to undefined method App\User::uspattern()

Comment: the method is inside the usershiftpattern model

Comment: public function uspattern(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
  }

Comment: the problem now is in your relationships, you need to define the inverse relationship in User model. I need to see your tables so that I can help you better

Comment: can I have you email? so i can share with you my database

Comment: Or can we chat through stack overflow ?

Comment: okay, i put my database inside your answer

Comment: maybe we can use github add me as your collabolator in the project willybabuu15@gmail.com, my reputation is too low to start a chart

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using github huhuhuhu :( wait will email you